# does the condition after && always get evaluated

Tags: php, conditional-statements, if-statement

I have this `if` statement that tests for the 2 conditions below. The second one is a function `goodToGo()` so I want to call it unless the first condition is already true

```
$value = 2239;

if ($value < 2000 && goodToGo($value)){
   //do stuff
}

function goodToGo($value){
   $ret = //some processing of the value
   return $ret; 
}
```

My question is about the 2 if conditions `$value < 2000` `&&` `goodToGo($value)`. Do they both get evaluated or does the second one only get evaluated when the first one is true?

In other words, are the following 2 blocks the same?

```
if($value < 2000 && goodToGo($value)) {
   //stuff to do
}

if($value < 2000) {
    if (goodToGo($value)){
       //stuff to do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

No--the second condition won't always be executed (which makes your examples equivalent).

PHP's `&&`, `||`, `and`, and `or` operators are implemented as "short-circuit" operators. As soon as a condition is found that forces the result for the overall conditional, evaluation of subsequent conditions stops.

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

```
// --------------------
// foo() will never get called as those operators are short-circuit

$a = (false && foo());
$b = (true  || foo());
$c = (false and foo());
$d = (true  or  foo());
```

Comment: I chose this later answer because it brings up a really good point about `(true  || foo())`. Would have thought the second one would evaluate since the first one is `true`, but looks like it's not the case. Good to know.

Comment: @brett, Yeah--the key is that for OR, you know it's going to be TRUE the first time you find a TRUE--no number of FALSEs will change that. For AND, you know it's going to be FALSE the first time you find a FALSE--no number of TRUEs will change that.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  The two blocks are the same.  PHP, like most (but not all) languages, uses *short-circuit evaluation* for `&&` and `||`.

Answer (score 6):

The two blocks ARE same.

PHP logical operators are "lazy", they are evaluated only if they are needed.
The following code prints "Hello, world!":

```
<?php
$a = 10;
isset($a) || die ("variable \$a does not exist.");
print "Hello, world!"
?>
```

Other logical operators includes &&, and, or.

```
<?php
perform_action() or die ('failed to perform the action');
?>
```

is a popular idiom.

Answer (score 2):

the second condition will only be checked if and only if first one is true, hence both statements are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the 2 code blocks you gave are equivalent.  PHP has short-circuiting, so when you use 
|| and &&, any statement after the first only gets evaluated when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Always corelate your technical Language with your own language, Likewise here, If I say you in verbal conversation, its just like :You are asking= "if I am hungry '&&' I am eating Pizza" is similar to "If I am hungry then only i am eating Pizza"?
So here you can see that later phrase says that untill i am not hungry i am not eating pizza, and the former says I am humgry and I am eating pizza. 
:-)

Comment: Now I am feeling Hungry :) But I dont eat Pizza