# How to avoid a fatal error in case Advanced Custom Fields plugin isn't activated?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

The Advanced Custom Fields docs always advises to start anything with verifications such as `<?php if(get_field('repeater_field_name')): ?>` but when the plugin isn't active this line triggers a fatal error. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try just using php's [`function_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) like so:

```
<?php
    if ( function_exists('get_field') && get_field('repeater_field_name') ):
        // do ACF things
    endif;
?>
```

Because `&&` [is a "short-cut" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2535578/947370) it checks from L to R and will bail out and immediately skip the entire `if` condition if the function doesn't exist (i.e. the plugin is disabled) and will never get to checking if `get_field('repeater_field_name')` evaluates as true. So you cannot reverse the order of the two conditions or it still won't work with the plugin disabled.

Comment: Thanks! Sub-question: do you consider this the best practice with ACF? That's relatively verbose and doing it every single time one outputs some ACF data sounds not ideal. Any suggestion?

Comment: Yeah, frequently there's not much point checking every time if your theme is heavily ACF dependent. If the site is "broken" without it, why do all that checking? Two suggestions if you don't want to do a check every time: 1) just include ACF in your theme and don't enable it as a plugin: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/including-acf-in-a-plugin-theme/  OR 2) put ACF in mu-plugins instead of plugins https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins

Comment: Actually including ACF into theme doesn't help with this issue at all.

Comment: Including it in the theme guarantees that ACF functions will be available when the theme is available. Your original question was about getting fatal errors when your turn off the ACF plugin (because the functions like get_field are no longer available). If you want to keep them separate so you can turn ACF and your theme on and off independently, then you should do the checks like in my answer above.

Comment: You're right, looks like I got things mixed up. Thanks! Just one little thing: I included ACF to my theme (following steps from https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/including-acf-in-a-plugin-theme/) but it's not showing up in the dashboard so I can't use it. Any idea why?

Comment: `// 3. Hide ACF field group menu item
add_filter('acf/settings/show_admin', '__return_false');` Remove this part during development. Then add it in for your production sites so your clients/site admins can't mess with your ACF structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the plugin is active using https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active but this works only on the admin side, on the frontend you will have to include plugin.php. I think the cleanest solution is to simply replace this line with your own wrapper function, e.g.

```
function my_get_field($fld) {
  if function_exists('get_field') return get_field($fld);
  return false; //or whatever value suits your purpose
}
```

Alternatively, if this is a temporary situation, just define your own dummy `get_field()` and remove it when you don't need it anymore.