# PHP how to do elseif final else statement to cover all other posibilities

Tags: php, redirect, server, header, geolocation

I have a georedirect code for cloudflare which goes as follows

```
<?php

$URI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$activepage = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$country_code = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];

if ($activepage=="www.example.co.uk" & $country_code=="CA") {
$link = 'http://www.example.us' . $URI;
header("location:$link");
exit;
}
elseif ($activepage=="www.example.co.uk" & $country_code=="US") {
$link = 'http://www.example.us' . $URI;
header("location:$link");
exit;
}
elseif ($activepage=="www.example.us" & $country_code=="GB") {
$link = 'http://www.example.co.uk' . $URI;
header("location:$link");
exit;
}
elseif ($activepage=="www.example.us" & $country_code=="UK") {
$link = 'http://www.example.co.uk' . $URI;
header("location:$link");
exit;
}

?>
```

effectively redirects UK/GB users from the US site back to the UK site, and US & Canadian users on the UK site over to the USD$ site (.us)

I want to add a final else statement so that all traffic which is not US or CA on the US site is redirected to the UK site (so for the rest of the world).

How am I best going about this?

Also this seems to be taking a long time to run (on a good server) how can I streamline this so it only runs as far as it needs to? E.g. the other elseif are not run in the background after the correct one is met? I thought the exit(); would do the trick but apparently not.

Thanks

Comment: Use `&&` instead of bitwise `&`.

Comment: thanks whats the significance of this @PHPglue ?

Comment: [& is a bitwise operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) however [&& is a logical operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: @PHPglue i thought a final statement of elseif ($activepage=="www.example.us") would cover all the rest of the countries but apparently not this just hangs and freezes?

Comment: You should just be able to `die;` or `exit;` *(parentheses not really needed)* after your final `elseif`. The page should `die;` when it's done being processed by Apache anyways, though, so I'm can't say why this would take any time to run.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to add a new `elseif` that identifies when "site is US, and traffic is not US, and traffic is not CA" and is redirected to the UK site.

Here is an idea of how to do that - I've tidied up the code a bit, married the conditions which had the same outcome, and tidied the logic (without changing it). It's not tested, but use it how you want:

```
$URI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$activePage = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$countryCode = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];
$redirectTld = '';

if (
    $activePage == 'www.example.co.uk' 
    && ($countryCode == 'CA' || $countryCode == 'US')
) {
    $redirectTld = 'us';
} elseif (
    $activePage == 'www.example.us'
    && ($countryCode == 'GB' || $countryCode == 'UK')
) {
    $redirectTld = 'co.uk';
} elseif (
    $activePage == 'www.example.us'
    && $countryCode != 'US'
    && $countryCode != 'CA'
) {
    $redirectTld = 'co.uk';
}

if ($redirectTld) {
    header('location: http://www.example.' . $redirectTld . $URI);
    exit;
}
```

Note that this won't be a catch all as the conditions need to be met still, if you want a true catch all you'll need to just have an `} else {` with no conditions (but that didn't seem to be what your question asked for :) )

You could tidy it up even further by getting the page's TLD instead of full URL for `$activePage` and just checking the url (but I don't know how all your data/info works).

> Also this seems to be taking a long time to run (on a good server) how
>   can I streamline this so it only runs as far as it needs to? E.g. the
>   other elseif are not run in the background after the correct one is
>   met? I thought the exit();

This tiny block of conditions shouldn't be a bottle neck, it could be the redirect time (redirecting and connecting to another URL or even server?), or something else.

PHP will stop evaluating a condition as soon as it cannot be met, and once one is met wont evaluate the others because they are "else".
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2535578/2632129